# vue dragged item dissapears after drop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component

Im trying to have two separated div that i can add articles from one div to another,but when I am trying to do so I am getting this error in console. Im using laravel too and my other question is can I send the left div (prof_added) details among other values as a form to laravel

Im using Vue-draggable 2.16.0  and vue 2.0.1

error :

```
vuedraggable.js?bcd0:277 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at spliceList (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:152), <anonymous>:277:32)
    at VueComponent.alterList (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:152), <anonymous>:266:13)
    at VueComponent.spliceList (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:152), <anonymous>:279:16)
    at VueComponent.onDragAdd (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:152), <anonymous>:336:16)
    at Sortable.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:152), <anonymous>:70:37)
    at _dispatchEvent (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:126), <anonymous>:1326:20)
    at Sortable._onDrop (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:126), <anonymous>:968:8)
    at Sortable.handleEvent (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:126), <anonymous>:1044:11)
```

My vue File which gets compiled :

```
<template>

  <div class="forceright col-md-12 ">
   <div class="forceright col-md-4  col-md-offset-right-1 ">

                    <div id="prof_skills" class="skilldiv">

                      <h3>Professional Skills</h3>
         <draggable class="drag-area" :list="profnew" :options="{animation:200, group:'status'}" :element="'article'" @add="onAdd($event, true)"  @change="update">
                    <article class="card alert alert-info skills" v-for="(profs, index) in profnew" :key="profs.prof_id" :data-id="profs.prof_id">
                        <header>
                            {{ profs.prof_skilldesc }}
                        </header>
                    </article>
                </draggable>   


</div>
</div>
 <div class="forceright col-md-4  col-md-offset-right-1 ">

                    <div id="prof_added" class="skilldiv">

                    <h3>Proffesional Skills Selected</h3>
        <draggable class="drag-area"  :list="profaddednew" :options="{animation:200, group:'status'}" :element="'article'" @add="onAdd($event, false)"  @change="update">

                </draggable>   


</div>
</div>


</div>   

</template>


<script>
  import draggable from 'vuedraggable'

    export default {
        components: {
            draggable
        },
        props: ['prof', 'profadded'],
        data() {
            return {
               profaddednew: this.profadded,
               profnew: this.prof
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onAdd(event) {
                let id = event.item.getAttribute('data-id');

            },
            update() {
                this.profaddednew.map((prof, index) => {
                    prof.order = index + 1;
                });

                this.profnew.map((prof, index) => {
                    prof.order = index + 1;
                });

                let profs = this.profaddednew.concat(this.profnew);


            }

        }
    }
</script>
<style>
 .drag-area{
     min-height: 10px;  
    }
</style>
```

And the bladepage

```
      <div id="app" name="profs">
       <info-list :profadded="{}" :prof="{{$prof}}"></info-list>
    </div>     
                    </div>
```

Comment: just an update! when i added v-for on profaddednew with artcile in it, now i can drag and drop but  the values go empty!And i actually want the left side to be empty so they can ony drag the right stuff in